# Call method(Context context) from non Activity Class in Android

Tags: android, class, android-context

I have 2 class, one with Activity and one non.
Here is this:

```
public class getinfo extends ContextWrapper
{
public String getemei(Context context)
    {
        TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
        mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
         return imei;
        }
}
```

**So how to call method `getimei` in `getinfo` class from Main Class ?**

//Edit, thanks, it done, this should be

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bnt;
   getinfo gif = new getinfo(null);   //edited-work fine
    @Overide
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     bnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String getemei = gif.getemei(getApplicationcontext()); //Work fine
                    tv.setText(getemei);

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you extending `ContextWrapper`?

Comment: `this` is not `Context` instance, so is inside click `Listener`. Use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: Use `String getemei = gif.getemei(MainActivity.this);'` And remove extend of ContextWrapper

Comment: that's use for context.getSystemservice in non Activity Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call method of a class by creating object of class

```
 getinfo gf=new getinfo();
```

//calling method

```
String a=gf.getemei(getApplicationContext());
```

or

directly call

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 bnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
    mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();

                tv.setText(imei);

            }
```

Comment: Thks, with getinfo gf=new getinfo(null); String a=gf.getemei(getApplicationContext());  its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

When using `this` inside of a listener you pass the instance of the object of whom you override the current method. You need to write `MainActivity.this`. Your code needs to look like this
`String getemei = gif.getemei(MainActivity.this);`

I would not suggest to implement the access to the IMEI like you did. The best practice here would be to stay with the [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and to use the Model to access such values.

Comment: thks, it's work well now, i just make this project to test for Worklight call native android code project.

Answer (score 0):

Non activity class with constructor

```
  public class getinfo extends ContextWrapper
    {
Context _con;
public getinfo(Context c)
{
_con=c;
}
    public String getemei()
        {
            TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
            mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) _con.getSystemService(_con.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String imei = mTelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
             return imei;
            }
    }
```

Activity class with implementation

```
         public class MainActivity extends Activity {
            Button bnt;
           getinfo gif;
            @Overide
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             bnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            gif=new getinfo(this); 
    String getemei=gif.getemei();
                            tv.setText(getemei);

                        }
            }
        }
```

use below code hope it will help you